# Differences between "static var" and "var" in Swift

Tags: swift, static, var

What is the main difference between "static var" and "var" in Swift? Can someone explain this difference to me, possibly with a little example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`static var` belongs to type itself while `var` belongs to instance (specific value that is of specific type) of type. For example:

```
struct Car {
    static var numberOfWheels = 4
    var plateNumber: String
}

Car.numberOfWheels = 3
let myCar = Car(plateNumber: "123456")
```

All cars has same amount of wheels. An you change it on type `Car` itself.

In order to change plate number you need to have instance of `Car`. For example, `myCar`.

Comment: FYI myCar has no property of `numberOfWheels`. There is NO such thing as `myCar.numberOfWheels`. Why because it's a property of the **class** *not* the **instance**. As a result you can do `Car.numberOfWheels = 7`

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a very nice Swifty example based on [this post](https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/ios-cell-registration-reusing-with-swift-protocol-extensions-and-generics-c5ac4fb5b75e#.wgt7x3izc). Though this is a bit more sophisticated.

Imagine you have a project in which you have 15 collectionViews in your app. For each you have to set the cellIdentifier & nibName. Do you really want to rewrite all code for your that 15 times?

There is a very POP solution to your problem:

Let's help ourselves by writing a protocol which returns a string version of our ClassName

```
protocol ReusableView: class {
    static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension ReusableView where Self: UIView {
    static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(Self)
    }
}
extension BookCell : ReusableView{
}
```

The same for the `nibName` of each custom cell you have created:

```
protocol NibLoadableView: class {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

extension NibLoadableView where Self: UIView {
    static var nibName: String {
        return String(Self)
    }
}

extension BookCell: NibLoadableView {
}
```

so now where ever I need `nibName` I would just do

```
BookCell.nibName
```

And where ever I need `cellIdentifier` I would just do:

```
BookCell.defaultReuseIdentifier
```

Now specifically to your question. Do you think we need to change the cellIdentifier per each new instance of BookCell?! No! All cells of BookCell will have the **same** identifier. It's not something that would change *per instance*. As a result it's been made `static`

While I did answer your question, the solution to reducing the number of lines for the 15 collectionViews can still be significantly improved so do see the blog post linked.

---

That blog post has actually been turned into a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeDxb_ucqr0) by NatashaTheRobot

Comment: It's great POP answer.

Answer (score 1):

A static var is property variable on a struct  versus an instance of the struct. Note that static var can exist for an enum too.

Example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static var foo:Int = 0
    var bar:Int
}

println("MyStruct.foo = \(MyStruct.foo)") // Prints out 0

MyStruct.foo = 10

println("MyStruct.foo = \(MyStruct.foo)") // Prints out 10

var myStructInstance = MyStruct(bar:12)

// bar is not 
// println("MyStruct.bar = \(MyStruct.bar)")

println("myStructInstance = \(myStructInstance.bar)") // Prints out 12
```

Notice the difference? bar is defined on an instance of the struct. Whereas foo is defined on the struct itself.